# Header image resizing HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with resizing the header image so that it fits the heading size. Both the image and the heading are in the same div but I can't seem to find the solution. I had one where it looked good on the laptop, but on a smartphone, where the screen is smaller, the image was way smaller than the heading.

I tried with several height units: %, em, rem and vh, but nothing seemed to work correctly. I also tried to have a fixed div height and using object-fit with contain or size-down + max height of the image as 100%, but that also didn't work. Additionally, I am not sure about giving the div a fixed height - won't it look out of scale when viewing on various devices?

What I need is to have the home icon on the left at the same level as the heading + both having the same height, no matter what device and screen size I'm on. The heading should stay centered. Does anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong? Below the html and css - one of many versions I checked.

Apologies if the code isn't very clean, it's only my second project.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Photo Gallery</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="gallery-styles.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="top-row">
      <a href="index.html">
        <img
          id="home-icon"
          src="data:image/png;base64,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"
      /></a>
      <h1 id="header">Luna's photos</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="gallery">
      <img src="Luna00.jpeg" />
      <img src="Luna01.jpeg" />
      <img src="Luna02.jpeg" />
      <img src="Luna03.jpeg" />
      <img src="Luna04.jpeg" />
      <img src="Luna05.jpeg" />
      <img src="Luna06.jpeg" />
      <img src="Luna07.jpeg" />
      <img src="Luna08.jpeg" />
      <img src="Luna09.jpeg" />
      <img src="Luna10.jpeg" />
      <img src="Luna11.jpeg" />
      <img src="Luna12.jpeg" />
      <img src="Luna13.jpeg" />
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
  background: black;
}

/* for header size visibility - remove later */
#top-row {
  border: 1px solid white;
}

#home-icon {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  display: block;
  max-height: 100%;
}

#header {
  background: black;
  color: white;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}

#gallery {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0 4px;
}

#gallery img {
  width: 25%;
  height: 300px;
  object-fit: cover;
  margin-top: 8px;
  padding: 0 4px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

@media (max-width: 800px) {
  #gallery img {
    width: 50%;
  }
}

a {
  color: darkgrey;
}

a:hover {
  color: black;
  background: darkgrey;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think JithinAji answer is a good solution.

You also asked for

> icon on the left at the same level as the heading + both having the same heigh

so if you prefer you can modify his code with

```
#top-row {
  border: 1px solid white;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content:center;
}

#home-icon {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  display: block;
  height: 2rem;
}

#header {
  background: black;
  color: white;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 2rem;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
```

Anyway if you have problem with really narrow smartphone display you can add a @media to reduce the #home-incon height and #header font-size like
for example:

```
@media (max-width: 320px) {
  #home-icon {
    height: 1.5rem;
  }

  #header {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! It worked for the most part, only the home icon is now next to the centered title and I was thinking about having it completely on the left side of the screen if possible. But I can see all three solutions give the result like yours, so maybe it's not possible? The @media is very useful, now I understand how it works!

Comment: I'm happy that it works. About the icon on the left i tried this, I'm not shure 100%, maybe you can adjust the position.                                                    
#home-icon {
    position:fixed;
    left: 22px;
    top: 24px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    display: block;
    height: 2rem;
  }

Answer (score 1):

Can you check if this is what you are looking for.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Photo Gallery</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="gallery-styles.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="top-row">
      <a href="index.html">
        <img
          id="home-icon"
          src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAOEAAADhCAMAAAAJbSJIAAAAhFBMVEX///8AAACampqgoKBOTk7p6ekpKSn8/Pz29va4uLhcXFzh4eH5+fkxMTEPDw/z8/NEREQ3NzcgICDl5eW/v788PDzX19dra2vHx8dJSUnt7e2oqKg1NTWEhIR9fX2xsbGRkZEVFRWKiookJCTR0dGAgICUlJR0dHRoaGhiYmJWVlYLCwtDLsDCAAAH+klEQVR4nO2d6WKyOhCGcV9QUVHc6kLlq229//s7Wm3BmSQMYQuceX+2LHkwzJaQWI26yyq7AbmLCasvJqy+mLD6YsLqq2jC4f7UbH0VecciCSd7z3pocZYedO4m1VV91wIJPxzrT/295KC9lVjuWHnbwggP29d2BTPRUf+SA1pWx1fduCDCoY0b1sSHzXUALctT3boQwuVa2DD3Gx7Y1iPcqm5eAOF115M17QisxJceYUd1+/wJL46ibc7ny7GrChK2vZjWrbuVJpwf45s3eq8w4V7VQUN5fxanYoTTuA4a6lhFQkoHDdU/VI7w3za+YS8K2rezLpUhnAYa7Tz6OlFpOYQ7vYaOdoLYzkTCS9IOmlrFEkpi0PoQfkhj0HoQDt0S+AokPA9K4SuOEGbxdSN803GBFSK8NqmNOeXwSxdA+EV11bt5Hm9r7oQTapBtP9KkzC1u3oTKMkVE/dPfKa1svWa+hOQYZhEt3GqF5uUQnvrERlzAie/EX75kwg01jd/56NzxwnxCn5oleW3h+Z8dwwlXxAY6J9kVfHmt2ADCLtWtrd8UV4ktp5ZHSCwUWp1VzIWopqpgQqqx7+3Q8CUajXlLnzJnT9gc0e7sIZzvwFpP4R9TJyVZE7aJQWi0XP/UT3g3asE/nxPVVvMmJLuIRReeevh9dzuf8F+iEdSSCKkuwkUWZhg1m4sl+O+V2vNzJqS6iB6KYbqgI/Y/4LU3+qFqdoRUk4BjGEEUag/hQVQPlBvhjGjWHTST5Fvs1wfwTdVNjjMipCYDAxjDjKWWEj+LlZbFyYSQ6uNdZCaVT8bbgKP9VkmETVqI3GvBGCbWDezm4AxyRpYlIdVbBfAXeSO8WNsDvF3i5Dgt4Zzo47cohjnRmrpGDyZhcpySkOrjB3AC3TfZauA4LtkIXSpC6uO04ZxRSgeNtBGFQElGWdMQEl+JfnMCTiR20FAojhvSLY4+ITUDRwnRl0bq7sDX+Hqihqq6hNQsYgsLhbqhiQfjOGotVpOQGITiIPtdvy5xhHHchWbmjiirjidsEx8feu46HTTUFsZxc1o5bnSU1rvEhP6O9gr04buTNlu/RQ3w55CE7VDOTjI7XkhITWMW0AVmUarvtXx4VVq37zfhiTJCaj+zoQ8jPu1YudB0zYhOufMOnZaIcEq82qgFrnY+Zjdkhpwj0eLgp44JW0QfhILsbGdCoZEAanBsreHDeSWkjpUgF5iiyCIRKnKQsyqQwUUJyXWmIzBbE+ovn0S9I7Rj1EjwNUaOEK6odSZYydYrPcQLZY4zcqlPSEj0ZMgFZjjSiYTe9i/iJAc79Kq/hBvi74DqYyliNIKwcyRWjsMhhSfhhXaeDetMCVIcTdm6Ru13dvyD8IN0Tg9mgZOMxnDVQgMgB5rFCa4hIa2ChwZzi5oMjF59n2Yz7PMvIWlOGgqlipwMjMw37e2w5w/CA+FYnAUmLlOkkmYW6v0QvhGMDEppsplhkESomE7yUoM7YfyBKEYjB4mZCuVqlEL1qmHN48xhD9XdV+XM5sYFAIJz9BrWd8whKKwobTb3vTEwcZjGmruxpf4QB3XQEmdz3zVCQ8dx6dCnpXIVeDoMdZQ0P6HSV0xXbaoIA8pgdeHCjkPpmXfyXuqgDroscTp+VHgUVjF61LQkn8C/pFgPncr44EesATTvjQ9ZVx1a4mUM8NSs7OsUaYQtoGSQbDSxGoLoBE/3abznUKdIJbw8ijBWbd5iGvQi9pBFLvWDGJkcNDou8GTrn8gbRCgLH525N+0HfEgwNxd4jnsWfCOcRl1AgCZM5lqISSfnH25spC79+JXv+WE4nOIJ1jeiluBK0RpNgGwsn1HlqPUwuI8qhn9YeK63E43ClZJG0NXHb2Oj27K9wZ+xjRnHXxaeByYWSqqA1IQrA6K0WOEpR3RCWgmufAnMP4nwaqwNReqgKI5COMtpNCIPOdikEgh1pkGWJSZkQvPFhExovpiQCc2Xo8gv6kHYFy73yoRMaJKYkAnNFxMyofliQiY0X0zIhOaLCZnQfDEhE5qv+hOO4Nzh2hH2NL5WZ0KzxIRMKFbH/pXbAXI721BOqNFdirnUo/7toJ+TOs9rujaQ+7y+8zLNMhfCXjiRf4Lkz/90Hoda3jST7yWzX85uB53vZ/nPC+Fm/fx53h0vN5EG5vMbitcGjpf0Ix1VM0Vq90inFk84lF3QUS3HK9C0coRbxUCuSNPwVTSLUNpLt4rpdyItTSWU7uKo3mwTq3qEbsILVY/QTnihWe0Jx+G3zkwoFhMyoUxMSJaxhJusCLvh5y41JTyHn5zVlLC7JTWGCZkwuZiQLCZ8igmzJ1wyIVVM+BQTMmFyMSFZkeyppoSRDJgJxcqLcCxb7IYJ0YWY8CEmNJgwuvBqPQmXlSPsoF1Z1TKWsCtbADjFGLBZhHPZykxJx/Gn1SOUbBQjU2S2SUUIVdNgRdpUjtBCy5IqdT3QGmMS4TYI1uv14q6BQrd/3w4L3OgUQLwWopGEKYQWF2ZCJkxDOMljLU0mZEImZML/GeGVuLdbdQnh6tpMyIRMyIQ5EOaxPjETMiETMiET1o0wjw0lmLBYwjy2bjOLMI9NJcwizGPnGi3CuIZoE+ax84lgj6N4wo16G6sg4XhmKPmSA9rytPYoabRViEHCQfeoMi/UuL7ibqqddJZNqfDWbAm0ackvrKOW8mnH7PdUAzFh9cWE1RcTVl9MWH3Vn/A/ffrIdwEnvgkAAAAASUVORK5CYII="
      /></a>
      <h1 id="header">Luna's photos</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="gallery">
      <img src="Luna00.jpeg" />
      <img src="Luna01.jpeg" />
      <img src="Luna02.jpeg" />
      <img src="Luna03.jpeg" />
      <img src="Luna04.jpeg" />
      <img src="Luna05.jpeg" />
      <img src="Luna06.jpeg" />
      <img src="Luna07.jpeg" />
      <img src="Luna08.jpeg" />
      <img src="Luna09.jpeg" />
      <img src="Luna10.jpeg" />
      <img src="Luna11.jpeg" />
      <img src="Luna12.jpeg" />
      <img src="Luna13.jpeg" />
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
  background: black;
}

/* for header size visibility - remove later */
#top-row {
  border: 1px solid white;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

#home-icon {
/*   position: absolute; */
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  display: block;
  height: 4rem;
}

#header {
  background: black;
  color: white;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 2rem;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

#gallery {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0 4px;
}

#gallery img {
  width: 25%;
  height: 300px;
  object-fit: cover;
  margin-top: 8px;
  padding: 0 4px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

@media (max-width: 800px) {
  #gallery img {
    width: 50%;
  }
}

a {
  color: darkgrey;
}

a:hover {
  color: black;
  background: darkgrey;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! It worked for the most part, only the home icon is now next to the centered title and I was thinking about having it completely on the left side of the screen if possible. I can see you commented out the position: absolute and that was the only way I managed to have it on the left side. But I can see all three solutions give the result like yours, so maybe it's not possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can solve your problem with these changes:

```css
#top-row {
  border: 1px solid white;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

#home-icon {
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  display: block;
  height: 40px;
}

#header {
  background: black;
  color: white;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! It worked for the most part, only the home icon is now next to the centered title and I was thinking about having it completely on the left side of the screen if possible. But I can see all three solutions give the result like yours, so maybe it's not possible?